# Is it possible to convert a .exe file to runnable Linux file?

Tags: linux, windows, executable

I have a file called ttsql in linux and windows machine. But that ttsql file builded separately for windows and linux. The windows file is working properly. But In linux , Which is not working. How Can i convert .exe into linux excutable file.

Comment: Looks like some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). You should edit your question to explain your real needs (and what this `ttsql` program does and why is it so important to you...). Perhaps you just want some interface to some database?

Answer (score 3):

In general it is not possible. You might try to use [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) (a sort-of Windows emulator) to run your Windows executable on Linux.

If possible, it is better to get a Linux equivalent, perhaps by porting and recompiling the source code (of your application) for Linux.

BTW, the impossibility to run a Windows executable on Linux is related to the essential differences between these two operating systems. I recommend reading [*Operating Systems : Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) to learn more about OSes.

Comment: I'm Using putty to work on linux. Is there any external third party software available for conversion @Basile Starynkevitch

Comment: No, there is not, and there cannot be. I suggest to solve your needs (which you did not explain) in some other way.